# How to implement function calls in interpreted programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm creating a interpreted programming language, and I want to support function calls.

I tried to implement this as follows. When the interpreter encounter a:

- function declaration, push it to the environment.
- function call, get the function declaration in the environment and execute its body.

I hesitated to use that approach, because it's not linear and seems to use too much resources.

In compiled programming languages, labels and goto are used to implement call functions. It's linear and stores only the reference of the function body.

For example, this C Code will produce that Assembly Code:

C code:

```
int sum (int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

sum(2, 3);
```

Assembly Code:

```
sum:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp + 8]
    mov edx, [ebp + 12]
    add eax, edx
    pop ebp
    ret

push 3
push 2
call sum
add esp, 8
```

I would like to implement an approach that resembles the approach used by compiled programming languages.

Comment: How are you handling this in general?   Is the program text as entered by the user converted to some internal form for storage?   Regardless of whether you store the raw program text or some more amenable internal form, you have to store it somewhere.  (I don't know what you mean by "push it to the environment").  At call time, you assign the actual parameters and start interpreting the stored function body.

Comment: Are you perhaps conflating "interpreted" and "interactive"?  By the latter, I mean that statements are executed immediately as they are entered.  This is not an invariable feature of an interpreted language.

Comment: When I say "push it to the environment", I mean to store the entire function declaration body, produced by the parser, in the symbol table, where variables are stored.

Comment: OK, so some representation of the code of the function is stored somewhere. What is the difficulty in causing it to execute at the appropriate time?

Comment: Is it ok to store an AST Node in the symbol table?

Comment: It's your program, you can do what you want.  On the other hand, where does code that is not a function body get stored, and why is this different?